# Is Islam the fastest growing religion in the world?

Tags: islam

Several sources have claimed that Islam is the "fastest growing religion":

For example:

> Islam is the fastest-growing religion in the world. [First paragraph of Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Growth_of_religion)

[The world's fastest-growing religion is ...(CNN)](http://edition.cnn.com/2015/04/02/living/pew-study-religion/)

[Islam is the 'fastest growing religion' and will 'overtake Christianity by the end of the century (Mirror.co.uk)'](http://www.mirror.co.uk/news/world-news/islam-fastest-growing-religion-overtake-6986333),

[This Anti-Islam video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0HTSwUig2-0)

I wanted to make sure if this is based on statistics and evidence.

(Presumably, this claim is about the *absolute* growth in adherents. Percentage growth is meaningless in the face of small religious.)

Comment: I watched the first 5 minutes of that video before giving up. Can someone provide a link to when the claim is made?

Comment: Anyway, this kind of statistics is always difficult to do correctly. For a start, you have to setup your definition of "having a religion": practicing the ritual ? self declaring ? just sharing the culture ? just being born from parents or in some area ? or possibly, counting more specialy the conversions ? Each of these question is legitime but would give different results. Plus transcultural surveys are even more prone to different feeling of the questions which bias the result. Sociologist survey and Mass media survey won't have the same reliability there !

Comment: You have cited a number of sources that give references. Given you have already done the research, why do you distrust the results?

Comment: Good point, seems like there isn't much more to it then. I suppose the references provided in the sources are accurate and suffice to accept the claim.

Comment: So can we close it?

Comment: Related, but about the USA, not the whole world: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/8910/is-atheism-the-fastest-growing-religion-in-the-history-of-the-united-states

Comment: @Oddthinking Yes, you may as well proceed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't a claim the OP is skeptical about.